# Forwarding hot-module-requests through nginx, in Docker

Tags: nginx, webpack, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy, hot-module-replacement

I'm working on Dockerizing a webpack application which supports hot-module replacement. Since I added an nginx front-end, I'm having trouble getting the hot-module-replacement to connect. Nginx serves the page, but the js bundle can't connect to the `webpack-dev-server` running in another Docker container.

The two things I think the problem could be stemming from is a domain resolution problem (between the Docker containers and nginx) or the request is missing the right upgrade / host headers.

The source code for this project [is here](https://github.com/NoahLE/Docker-nginx-hot-module-replacement).

I have two docker containers in this project:

- `app-webpack` - A `webpack-dev-server` which serves the website
- `app-nginx` - The reverse-proxy

My nginx config files are in `docker/nginx`.

Ideally, the user goes to `localhost`, which nginx picks up and redirects to `app-webapp:3000`. The webpack-dev-server then sends the hot-module-replacement code via the `socketjs-node` socket address and the page updates locally.

I've confirmed that the `app-webpack` container can serve a HMR capable page.

Thanks in advance for the help and let me know if there's additional info I can provide!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took a little bit of tinkering but it turns out I was upgrading the headers incorrectly. For anyone referencing this in the future, check out the linked repo for the full source code.

Here's my `etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;

    # The server settings
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

And the `etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf/`

```
# If we receive X-Forwarded-Proto, pass it through; otherwise, pass along the
# scheme used to connect to this server
map $http_x_forwarded_proto $proxy_x_forwarded_proto {
  default $http_x_forwarded_proto;
  ''      $scheme;
}

# If we receive X-Forwarded-Port, pass it through; otherwise, pass along the
# server port the client connected to
map $http_x_forwarded_port $proxy_x_forwarded_port {
  default $http_x_forwarded_port;
  ''      $server_port;
}

# If we receive Upgrade, set Connection to "upgrade"; otherwise, delete any
# Connection header that may have been passed to this server
map $http_upgrade $proxy_connection {
  default upgrade;
  '' close;
}

# Apply fix for very long server names
server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;

# Set appropriate X-Forwarded-Ssl header
map $scheme $proxy_x_forwarded_ssl {
  default off;
  https off;
}

gzip_types text/plain text/css application/javascript application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
log_format vhost '$host $remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                 '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                 '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';

# HTTP 1.1 support
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_buffering off;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection $proxy_connection;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $proxy_x_forwarded_proto;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl $proxy_x_forwarded_ssl;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $proxy_x_forwarded_port;

# Mitigate httpoxy attack (see README for details)
proxy_set_header Proxy "";

server {
    server_name _; # This is just an invalid value which will never trigger on a real hostname.
    listen 80;
}

server {
    server_name localhost;
    listen 80;

    location /sockjs-node/ {
        proxy_pass https://app-webapp:3000/sockjs-node/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://app-webapp:3000;
    }
}
```